# The difference in using first and firstly

Tags: word-usage

> One should first use the tool which...

Is it right in using the word "first"?

Both *firstly* and *first* seem to have the same adverbial meaning.

Comment: First, the way you have used _first_ in that opening sentence is perfectly fine. Second, I believe the issue regarding the use of _second_ or _secondly_ is even more tricky than _first_ and _firstly_. There is some good reading about this at [this ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/firstly-or-first).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that phrase sounds perfectly fine.

I've never actually heard or used the word "firstly".  [This](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/firstly) says that Chicago Manual of Style and other style guides recommend against using it.  It sounds old and overly formal.

(It might be used in British English, but I am not British, so I don't know.)